# Moq setup not returning Return Value

Tags: c#, moq

For some reason my mock setup doesn't seem to be working properly.

This is my Moq setup:

```
_mockMfgViewRespository
            .Setup(r => r.Find(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<V_YO_POP_MFGITM, bool>>>(), It.IsAny<bool>(), It.IsAny<Expression<Func<V_YO_POP_MFGITM, object>>>())).
            Returns(GenerateViewReturnData());
```

Where GenerateViewReturnData returns a Queryable collection of type V_YO_POP_MFGITM.

```
 Expression<Func<V_YO_POP_MFGITM, bool>> filter = x => x.VENDORID.Equals(vendorId) && x.VENDOR_SKU.Equals(partNumber);

            var viewResult = uow.MfgViewRepository.Find(filter);
```

viewResult always has an empty enumeration. I've tried every combo I can think of and my collection is never returned.

EDIT: Added Mock Setup:

```
 _mockMfgRepository = new Mock<IGenericRepository<YO_POP_MFGPO>>();
        _mockMfgViewRespository = new Mock<IGenericRepository<V_YO_POP_MFGITM>>();
        _mockFactory = new Mock<IUnitOfWorkFactory>();

        var uow = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        uow.SetupGet(x => x.MfgRepository).Returns(_mockMfgRepository.Object);
        uow.SetupGet(x => x.MfgViewRepository).Returns(_mockMfgViewRespository.Object);

        _mockFactory.Setup(f => f.Create()).Returns(uow.Object);
```

Comment: What does GenerateViewReturnData?

Comment: Provide more context in a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. Not much help can be provided without it.

Comment: GenerateViewReturnData returns IQueryable<V_YO_POP_MFGITM> that has records in it of type V_YO_POP_MFGITM.

In my Setup call, there are three params being passed in, but the last two are optional params. But MOQ makes you put them in anyway.

As far as more context, this is pretty much all the code there is. That's why it's so confusing that Setup and Return aren't working as they should.

Comment: @g.t.w.d they are confusing to you. That is why we need to see the code to better understand where the mistake is. We can't magically admit to be able to see your code to tell you where the problem is. you need to show us the code so we don't blow our cover.

Comment: What I'm telling you is that, besides setting up the mocks, this is the entire code. I'll add the mock setups in the initialize method if that helps. But that's really it.

Comment: See...you are using generics. Could not tell that from initial post. show the definition of the interfaces that you are mocking.

Comment: The whole purpose of providing a [mcve] is so that we can avoid this waste of time back and forth trying to clarify your question. You are just going to have to update the question with the relevant details.

Comment: also, did you put a breakpoint to step in the mocking code that is executed?